# Why is CSS Pseudo-element overflowing parent container even with absolute dimensions set and quote appearance different Chrome x Firebase?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components, pseudo-element

1. I am trying to understand why is my pseudo-element (big blockquotes) overflowing the parents container, even after  using absolute values for the `width` and `height`.

I have created a demo with an adaptation of the bad functioning code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pseudo-element-overflowing-wrohd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
On the demo, I have pushed the `element` containing the `pseudo-elements` to the bottom of the `document` to reveal the issue.

Here is the `CSS` for the `<blockquote>` element.

On the desktop, a big blank space opens below the `html` document, a consequence of the `::after` `pseudo-element` overflowing it´s parent container.

```
export const Quote = styled.blockquote`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 80px;
    content: open-quote;
    color: red;
    font-size: 7rem;
    font-family: ABeeZee;
    left: -44.8px;
    top: -19.3px;
    z-index: 5;
    @media (min-width: 50rem) {
      font-size: 10rem;
      left: -70px;
      top: -50px;
    }
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 80px;
    content: close-quote;
    color: red;
    font-size: 7rem;
    font-family: ABeeZee;
    right: -44.8px;
    bottom: -15px;
    z-index: 5;
    @media (min-width: 50rem) {
      font-size: 10rem;
      right: -70px;
    }
  }
```

How can I position these big quotes correctly? Another problem is that the quotes are not being positioned at the center of the `pseudo-elements`.

2. Why is are the quotes looking different, in Chrome and Firefox?

In Firefox the quotes look perfect, but on Chrome the quotes loose their curving, becoming two sticks, like presented below, regardless of which `font-family` I use:

[image: Bad QUote]

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `flex: 0 0 290px;` on `export const About = styled.article` in styled.js supposed to be there? It is creating a large space at the bottom of the container `<article>`.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that flex-basis is doing this? I guess that I am just defining the minimum basis of the element. If you rip the ::after quote off, the blank space dissapears. I guess there is something wrong with the pseudo-element. Actually I do not know yet, that is why I am asking here =D